# The Late Philip J Fry Time Machine

Tags: futurama

Farnsworth built the Time Machine allowing them to only go forwards in time, to prevent something stupid happening like Fry being his own grandfather.  As the story progressed, there was actually a time period where a backwards time machine was made.

Why didn't they go on one in another universe to get that time machine to go back in time so far that it reached their own universe?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because it was faster and less complicated just to spin around to the next universe again. It took, what, 30 seconds?

Comment: You'd think resetting things to their "original state" would be more comforting, but they were willing to kill Hitler, but then leave Elanor Roosevelt as dead, so it seemed like they truly didn't care.  I'm surmising 2 another issues were: 1) there would've been a big feud between bender wanting to stop by in the "terminator judgement day" year, vs. Fry and the professor's year of prefence, and 2) the advanced race were so sure of being able to create a backwards time machine, but failed anyways.  There was no guarantee others would be able to deliver.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because they didn't want to run into themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Because the Professor and Fry didn't want to stay in the time that Bender wanted to, when they found the time with a backwards time machine Bender got back at them by going further into the future.